# Unable to configure Intellij Web App deployment corrrectly

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm creating a Java web application using JSP and Servlets, TomCat 9 and IntelliJ. The tutorial I'm following uses Eclipse, where the instructor just runs the project as Run As > Run On Server and everything works seamlessly.

In IntelliJ, things seem all messed up.

This is my project structure -

[image]

This is the Run Configuration -

[image]

[image]

I have the `web.xml` setup as -

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.do</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

So, any requests to `localhost:8080`, or in the case of IntelliJ, `http://localhost:8080/jspservlet_war_exploded/` should be redirected to `login.do`, which is handled by `LoginServlet` -

```
package app;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/login.do")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String name = req.getParameter("name");
        String pass = req.getParameter("password");
        req.setAttribute("name", name);
        req.setAttribute("password", pass);

        RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("views/login.jsp");
        requestDispatcher.forward(req, resp);


    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String name = req.getParameter("name");
        req.setAttribute("name", name);
        RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("views/welcome.jsp");
        requestDispatcher.forward(req, resp);
    }
}
```

At first, I was testing the `doGet()` method in `LoginServlet`, by just manually adding the `?name=xxx&password=xxx` query string in the start page - `http://localhost:8080/jspservlet_war_exploded/`. These attributes were set in the `request` and then forwarded to `login.jsp`, which would just display the attribute values using `${name}` and `${password}`. Things worked fine until this step.

Then, I changed the `login.jsp` page to include a simple `form` that has an input field to enter the user's name, and have it sent to `/login.do` via the `action` attribute, **using the `POST` method**. This is where things blew up.

Here is `login.jsp` -

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<p>Time on server is <%= new Date()%></p>
<%--<p>Your name is ${name} and password is ${password}</p>--%>
<p>pageContext.request.contextPath: ${pageContext.request.contextPath}</p>

<form action="/login.do" method="post">
    <label for="inp">Enter your name </label>
    <input id="inp" type="text" name="name"/>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

which results in this page -

[image]

Now, as soon as I hit "submit", the request seems to go to `localhost:8080/login.do` (because that's what the `action` attribute's value is), and that throws an error -

[image]

Based on the other questions I've read here, it looks like that happens because the context path (ie. root of the application) is `http://localhost:8080/jspservlet_war_exploded/`, and all locations are relative to this path(?). So, the recommended way seems to be `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`.

Based on that, if I change the `action` attribute to `action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login.do"`, then things work again.

However, now I'm trying to redirect from the `doPost()` method in `LoginServlet` to `TodoServlet`, like so -

`resp.sendRedirect("/todo.do");`

This again causes a 404, because the URL becomes `http://localhost:8080/todo.do`, whereas it should be `http://localhost:8080/jspservlet_war_exploded/todo.do`.

How do I fix things so that all resources are deployed relative to `http://localhost:8080/jspservlet_war_exploded/` by default, and I can just specify the URL pattern directly in `action` or `resp.sendRedirect()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the deployment context in the Run/Debug configuration:

[image: Context]

If you want the app to work with any context you should use the relative paths instead like [described here](https://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/how-to-send-redirect-from-java-servlet).

Instead of `resp.sendRedirect("/todo.do");` use `resp.sendRedirect("todo.do");` or `resp.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/todo.do");`

Comment: Thank You..That helped.

Answer (score 0):

did you try this :

```
resp.sendRedirect("todo.do");
```